# Why does this code do not work? (countdown)

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a code and a function that takes the name of the event and the date/time of the event and returns the time till the event. I would like to know what is wrong with the code.

```
<p style="color:red;font-size:20px;" id="C1_Counter"></p>

<script>

CD1(New_Year, "January 1, 2022 00:00:00")

function CD1(event_name, event_date) {
var C1 = "event_name = ";
var C1_Date = new Date(event_date).getTime();
var C1_Counter = document.getElementById("C1_Counter");
setInterval(() => countDown(C1, C1_Date, C1_Counter), 1000);
}

function countDown(x,time, elm) {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the time parameter
  var distance = time - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element we got from the parameter elm
  elm.innerHTML = x + days + " days " + hours + " hours "
  + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    console.log(elm);
    elm.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you explain what's wrong with the code. Are getting an error? Or a wrong output?

Comment: Does not get any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code throws the error `ReferenceError: New_Year is not defined` (you can see it in the browser console). If I understand correctly, you just forgot the quotes around the string. So try to replace:

```js
CD1(New_Year, "January 1, 2022 00:00:00")
```

with:

```js
CD1("New_Year", "January 1, 2022 00:00:00")
```

Also, you need to interpolate an argument into a string. So try to replace:

```js
var C1 = "event_name = ";
```

with:

```js
var C1 = event_name + " = ";
```

or with:

```js
var C1 = `${event_name} = `;
```

Comment: Yes thank you. Now I want to extend the function that allows to define the variable name (C1) as an argument of the function. I wrote a simple extension but does not seem to work. I will appreciate an advice.

Comment: @lemond_2021 Sorry, still not sure if I understand the question. Maybe it is worth to create a new question about just this issue.